# tlp stops working after suspend and resume

Tags: power-management, laptop, alpine-linux

I use tlp for power management on my Asus UX305FA, and it improves battery time from ~7h to about ~11h.

However, apparently it stops working after I close and open lid, which causes acpi to perform `pm-suspend` as configured in `/etc/acpi/LID`.

After I open the lid the estimated time to discharge drops dramatically. It recovers when I call `sudo service tlp restart`.

I tried to call `tlp stat` before and after closing the lid, and there's some difference that looks relevant:

```
104,105c104,105
< /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode               =     2
< /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs =  6000
---
> /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode               =     0
> /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs =   500
117c117
<   APM Level = 128
---
>   APM Level = 254
126,127c126,127
< /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy  = min_power
< /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy  = min_power
---
> /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
> /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
151c151
< wlan0(iwlwifi)                : wifi, connected, power management = on
---
> wlan0(iwlwifi)                : wifi, not connected, power management = off
```

Apparently some of the settings governed by tlp revert to default after the laptop is awoken. Is there a way to set them automatically on resume?